# usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device

Tags: usb

My computer running Ubuntu 22.04 keeps printing the following error into my terminal every ~15 seconds (the numbers in italic change every time the error is printed):

```
[*1118.3875994*] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[*1119.3789753*] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[*1119.3758975*] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[*1120.9587903*] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[*1120.8795834*] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address *94*, error -32
[*1120.6108934*] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address *95* read/64, error -32
[*1121.2957146*] usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I'm not sure why it keeps spitting this into the terminal and why it's doing it so frequently – I have nothing in any of the USB ports. Plus, it wasn't doing this the last I booted up the computer.

And if this is just a faulty USB port and not an ubuntu/software issue – how could I suppress these error messages? They're really annoying.